# Jquery check if all inputs are empty before sending the form

Tags: jquery, forms, validation

I need to insert a jquery control that looks if all the input fields of a form are empty or not. If they are empty, or just one of them is empty, the validation fails.

I get the result with one input field, here u are the code:

```
$(function(){
    $('#btnSubmit').on('click',checkEmpty);
});

function checkEmpty(){


    var isEmpty=$('#inputId').val();   
    if (isEmpty == 0 || isEmpty == "") {
        fail.text('empty field');
        return false;
    }else{
        return true;
    }
}
```

But things get wrong when I try the same with two or more imput fields:

```
$(function(){
    $('#btnSubmit').on('click',checkEmpty);
});

function checkEmpty(){

    var fail=$('#failText');

    $("formId input").each(function() {
        if($.trim($(this).val()) === ""){
            fail.text('empty field');
            return false;
        }
    });

}
```

In this case the text "empty field" appears only inthe first #failText id field, not in the second, and then the form send me into the relative php page, without stopping the sending.

Comment: Why not add `required` attribute on `input` elements.

Comment: because you're `returning false` inside of the `each` (which breaks the loop), but doesn't return from the function

Comment: wow! that's right now, billyonecan. And about the only one field filled wit the text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your checkEmpty function does not return false. (you are returning false only within your each loop)

Rewrite your checkEmpty function to something like this:

```
function checkEmpty(){

var fail=$('#failText');
var failCount = 0;

$("formId input").each(function() {
    if($.trim($(this).val()) === ""){
        fail.text('empty field');
        failCount++;
        return false;
    }
});

if(failCount > 0){
return false;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsbin.com/deliqi/1/edit?html,js,console,output

```
  var emptyInputs = $("input").filter(function(){
    return !$.trim(this.value);
  }).length > 0;

  if(emptyInputs) // do stuff
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because when you do `$('#failText')` it only selects the first instance of that ID. If you want to select all instances then assign a class.

**But** in your case you don't want to do that too because you want to show "field empty" message on the fields that are empty not all so you gotta assign different id to them.

**Have a look at this demo : https://jsfiddle.net/Lpzp2jj5/8/**

Answer (score 0):

Studing your answers, I get this solution:

```
function isEveryInputEmpty() {
    var failCount = ($('#formId input').length)-1;
    var txTarget=$('#formId #txTargetResult');

    $('#formId input').each(function() {

        if ($(this).val() === '') {
            txTarget.text('empty field');
            failCount++;
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Works fine to me